# How to add multiple options to the Dismissible Widget in Flutter like Image below

Tags: flutter, widget

[image: Here is referecne to the title]

I've tried the confirm dismiss parameter in the Dismiss widget but it's only a dialog that is recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `Dismissible` widget does not support that.

You can either build it yourself using `Row`, `Icon` and `GestureDetector`, or you can consider using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

[image: demo gif taken from the package]